# OpenCL clCreateProgramFromSource() segfaults with address of single string #included

Tags: c, pointers, opencl

Calling clCreateProgramFromSource on a single source with the strings arg set the the address of an #included character array segfaults, but passing the array in as an element of a character pointer array works.

```
#include "prog_src.h"
const char *cl_srcs[1];
cl_srcs[0] = prog_src_cl;

cl.prog = clCreateProgramWithSource(cl.context, 1, cl_srcs, NULL, &err);
puts("test0");
cl.prog = clCreateProgramWithSource(cl.context, 1, &prog_src_cl, NULL, &err);
puts("test1");
```

"test0" will print and then the program segfaults, i'm not sure why it doesn't work with the second version, prog_src_cl is an unsigned char * in the file #included.

Any help would be much appreciated as i cant seem to wrap my head around why something so seemingly trivial doesnt work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `clCreateProgramWithSource` expects the source to be passed via the parameter `const char** strings`. You say `prog_src_cl` is a character array. This means that `&proc_src_cl` is of type `const char (*)[N]`. (Pointer to N-element array of constant characters, where N is probably the length of the string used to initialise the array, plus 1 for the nul termination character.) This is not the same as `const char**`, and you cannot safely convert between them!

I recommend you turn on more type checking options in your C compiler, for example by passing `-Wextra` to clang or gcc. For example, clang catches this programming error in the `-Wincompatible-pointer-types` warning, which is included in `-Wextra`.

Comment: Thanks, I believe gcc did warn me but I typecasted it away as I didn't think `(*)[N]` was any different from `**`.  The more you know I guess. Odd behaviour.